# How can I round down a decimal?

Tags: java, printing, casting

I am writing a program that will simulate a cash register change calculator. It should print the change and how to give back the change ( number of twenty, tens, fives, quarters, dimes, etc).

The problem is that when I compile the program, I get a big number. I've tried rounding it down but it doesn't work. ALSO, I don't know if it is caused by the change not being rounded but I won't get the number of cents, I only get 1 $10 bill.

p.s. I am taking a high school CS course and right now I can't use other methods of rounding it, I know there is a way like the one I attempted below (casting and stuff) which I am allowed to use at the moment.

Thank you.

```
public class changeCash
  {
   public static void main(String[] args)
     {

        double cost = 68.90;
        double amtPaid = 80.00;
        double change = 0;
        int twentyBill= 0;
        int tenBill = 0;
        int fiveBill = 0;
        int oneBill = 0;
        int quarters = 0;
        int dimes = 0;
        int nickels = 0;
        int pennies = 0;



        change = amtPaid - cost;

        change =  ((int)change * 10) / 10.0;
        System.out.println("Your change is " +"$" + change);

        double back = amtPaid - cost;
        if(back >= 20)
        {
            twentyBill++;
            back -= 20;
            System.out.println(twentyBill + " $20 bill(s)");
        }

        else if(back >= 10)
        {
            tenBill++;
            back -= 10;
             System.out.println(tenBill + " $10 bill(s)");
        }

        else if(back >= 5)
        {
            fiveBill++;
            back -= 5;
            System.out.println(fiveBill + " $5 bills(s)");
        }

        else if(back >= 1)
        {
            oneBill++;
            back -= 1;
            System.out.println(oneBill + " $1 bills(s)");
        }

        else if(back >= 0.25)
        {
            quarters++;
            back -= 0.25;
            System.out.println(quarters + " qaurter(s)");
        }

        else if(back >= 0.10)
        {
            dimes++;
            back -= 0.10;
            System.out.println(dimes + " dime(s)");
        }

        else if(back >= 0.05)
        {
            nickels++;
            back -= 0.05;
            System.out.println(nickels + " nickel(s)");
        }

        else if(back >= 0.01)
        {
            pennies++;
            back -= 0.01;
            System.out.println(pennies + " penny(ies)");
        }



   }
}
```

Comment: Also, I could be not seeing something, but:
    `if(back >= 20)
        {
            twentyBill++;
            back -= 20;
             System.out.println(twentyBill + " $20 bill(s)");
        }`

won't actually add a bunch of 20 dollar bills. You'll need to use a while loop to keep adding 20s until there are no more 20s to be added. Also, once it sees a 20, it won't go into the 10s and so on, because you have else ifs, not ifs.

Comment: Here is the complete code:  http://ideone.com/9PSFz8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of issues. First, smaller one:

```
change = amtPaid - cost;
```

Change is 11.1, as it should be, but then:

```
change = ((int)change * 10) / 10.0;
```

Casts take precedence over arithmetic, so *first* `(int)change` happens (which results in 11), *then* it is multiplied by 10, then divided by 10.0, and you end up with 11.0 instead of 11.1.

But your bigger problem is in your `if` statements. You have a series of `if...else`. Once one of these executes, the remainder of the `else` blocks will not. So when you have e.g.:

```
if (back >= 20) {
    ...
} else if (back >= 10) {
    ...
} else if (back >= 5) { 
    ...
} else ...
```

As soon as one hits, it's done. If `back >= 20` is false it goes to the next. Then if `back >= 10` is true, it executes that, then doesn't execute the rest, so you would want to separate them, e.g.:

```
if (back >= 20) {
   ...
}
if (back >= 10) {
   ...
}
if (back >= 5) {
   ...
}
...
```

That'll get you closer, but you're still not quite there. For example, what if your change is 40? That will be two 20's. But your `if` statement will only take away a single 20. To that end, a `while` loop would be appropriate. It also more accurately reflects reality. In real life if you had to give somebody $40, you wouldn't just give them a single $20 and walk away, you'd get a dirty look. You'd keep giving them $20's until the amount you owed them was less than $20. So for example:

```
while (back >= 20) {
   ...
}
while (back >= 10) {
   ...
}
while (back >= 5) {
   ...
}
...
```

You want your code to reflect the logic you would use in reality.

---

Regarding your question in comments:

> ... why do I get $11.099999999999994 instead of just 11.1?

Floating-point rounding error. Decimal numbers are not 100% accurate; "11.1" can't be represented precisely. You have a couple of ways to work around it. You could round to two decimals when you *display* the number, e.g. `System.out.printf("%.2f", change)`. However, you may want to use `int` and store the number of *cents*, rather than using `double` and storing the number of *dollars*. Working with integers is more precise, and actually, when working with currency in important applications, integers are often used for this reason.

Comment: Oh ok I will get rid of the else's, but why do I get $11.099999999999994 instead of just 11.1?

Comment: @NatCarbonell Floating-point rounding error. Decimal numbers are not 100% accurate; "11.1" can't be represented precisely. You have a couple of ways to work around it. You could round to two decimals when you *display* the number, e.g. `System.out.printf("%.2f", change)`. However you may want to use `int` and store the number of *cents*, rather than using `double` and storing the number of *dollars*. Working with integers is more precise, and actually, when working with currency in important applications, integers are often used for this reason.

Comment: @NatCarbonell because of floating-point precision - read http://floating-point-gui.de/ .. in C# I would tell you to use the `decimal` type instead of `double`.. not sure if there's a java equivalent. `BigDecimal`?

Comment: @JasonC You could add the information about floating point error into the answer.  I think it's too important to be buried in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

**Simpler Solution**

```
double d = 2.99999999;
long l = (long) d;
```

**Math.class**, [floor function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html)

```
double d = Math.floor(2.55555) //result: 2.0
```

> Returns the largest (closest to positive infinity) double value that
>   is less than or equal to the argument and is equal to a mathematical
>   integer

Answer (score -1):

Find below the code which works well. Tested with different values. We want to avoid more than 2 decimal places hence I have added several utility methods just to do that.

Uncomment different cost values to see its working in different scenarios.

public class ChangeCash {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    double cost = 65.90;
    // cost = 68.33;
    // cost = 42.27;
    double amtPaid = 80.00;
    double change = 0;

    int twentyBill = 0;
    int tenBill = 0;
    int fiveBill = 0;
    int oneBill = 0;
    int quarters = 0;
    int dimes = 0;
    int nickels = 0;
    int pennies = 0;

    change = amtPaid - cost;

    System.out.format("Your change is $ %.2f", decimalCeil(change, true));
    System.out.println();
    double back = decimalCeil(change, true);
    if (back >= 20) {
        twentyBill++;
        back -= 20;
        System.out.println(twentyBill + " $20 bill(s)");
    }

    if (back >= 10) {
        tenBill++;
        back -= 10;
        System.out.println(tenBill + " $10 bill(s)");
    }

    if (back >= 5) {
        fiveBill++;
        back -= 5;
        System.out.println(fiveBill + " $5 bills(s)");
    }

    if (back >= 1) {
        oneBill = (int) (back * 10) / 10;
        back -= oneBill;
        System.out.println(oneBill + " $1 bills(s)");
    }
    if (decimalCeil(back) >= 0.25) {
        quarters = (int) (back * 100) / 25;
        back = correct2DecimalPlaces(back, 25);
        System.out.println(quarters + " qaurter(s)");
    }
    back = (int) (decimalCeil(back, true) * 100);
    if (back >= 10) {
        dimes = (int) (back / 10);
        back = back % 10;
        System.out.println(dimes + " dime(s)");
    }
    if (back >= 5) {
        nickels = (int) (back / 5);
        back = back % 5;
        System.out.println(nickels + " nickel(s)");
    }
    if (back >= 1) {
        pennies = (int) back;
        System.out.println(pennies + " penny(s)");
    }
}

private static double correct2DecimalPlaces(double back, int modulo) {
    int correctTwoPlaces = (int) (back * 100) % modulo;
    back = (double) correctTwoPlaces / 100;
    return back;
}

private static double decimalCeil(double change) {
    int temp = (int) (change * 100);
    double tempWithCeil = Math.ceil(temp);
    double answer = tempWithCeil / 100;
    return answer;
}

private static double decimalCeil(double change, boolean decimalThreePlaces) {
    double temp = change * 1000;
    double tempWithCeil = Math.ceil(temp);
    double answer = tempWithCeil / 1000;
    return answer;
}
```

}

Comment: Hey! Did you try my code. I spent some time there ;-) When I last saw, it worked successfully. I am not sure why the down vote but let me know what are you expecting.